# How to simplify expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

What are some ways to simplify the following expression?

```
(A <= B && B <= C) || (A <= D && D <= C) || (B <= A && A <= D && D <= C) || (D >= C && A <= B && B <= C ) || (B <= A && D >= C)
```

Are there online calculators for this?

Comment: Use ``FullSimplify``: ``(A <= B && B <= C) || (A <= D && D <= C) || (B <= A && A <= D && D <= C) || (D >= C && A <= B && B <= C) || (B <= A && D >= C) // FullSimplify`` This gives you ``(D >= C && B <= A) || (A <= B && B <= C) || (A <= D && D <= C)``. Furthermore, avoid using capital letters for your symbols.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Comment: @Domen Сould you show your request for WolframAlpha?  
If I use this query  
`FullSimplify[(a <= b && b <= c) || (a <= d && d <= c) || (b <= a && a <= d && d <= c) || (d >= c && a <= b && b <= c ) || (b <= a && d >= c)]`  
Then I don't get an answer

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: This site is for Q&A about the software application Mathematica and the Wolfram Language. Questions solely about Wolfram|Alpha are not appropriate for this site. See [`What topics can I ask about here?`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Note that Wolfram Alpha isn't your only free option, though: [Wolfram Cloud (which is basically Mathematica in your browser) is open access.](https://wolframcloud.com)

Comment: @thorimur Thanks